# Highcharts (Highstock): Get data from external CSV, doesn't display date correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, csv, highcharts

I'm trying for days now to get Highstock working with an external CSV file. The issue was first that the imported file was sorted in "descending" order whereas Highcharts requires the data to be sorted in "ascending" order. Once I found a JSFiddle/Codepen close to my problem, I managed to display the data correctly. 
Now the problem is that on the x-axis the dates are displayed as something like `00:00:00.500` whereas it should be looking like this `2016-03-11`.

I have created a codepen since it may be easier for you to respond to it than copy/pasting here a lot of code: [http://codepen.io/bauhausweb/pen/aNpbxg](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzNQBN)

Thanks for looking into my issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, there seems to at least be the problem of `2016-03-11` simply being a string and not a timestamp in milliseconds, which causes it to chose the defaults of 0, 1, 2, ... as x-values instead.

Below I've provided an example of how you can use the data modules `csv` attribute to achieve a similar result, with the help of the `complete` function:

```
$(function () {
    $.get("https://www.example.com/my.csv", function (csv) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            data: {
                complete: function(o) {
                    o.series[0].data.reverse();
                },
                csv: csv
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or look at [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kcb8ec4w/).

Comment: Hi @halvor-strand, thanks a lot! I was searching like a maniac for a simple way "to reverse the sort order (to ascending) of a remote CSV file" - but the only thing I found were similar JSFiddles and Codepens which were not giving me the exact answer I would understand. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
 $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {

      if (lineNo > 0 && lineNo < 557) {

        var items = line.split(',');
        // var seriesname = String(items[0]); // this is the area name
        var seriesname = "Gold"; // this is the area name
        var price = parseFloat(items[1]);
        var f_date =  items[0];
        var format = String(f_date.replace(/-/g,','));
        var date_items = format.split(',');
        var d = Date.UTC(date_items[0],date_items[1],date_items[2]);
        console.log(d); 
        var date = d;

        // this will be the id of the drilldown
        // var shift_one_value = parseFloat(items[3]); // drilldown shift1 value
        // var shift_two_value = parseFloat(items[4]); // drilldown shift2 value

        series.data.push({ 
          name: seriesname,
          y: price,
          x: date
        });

      }


    });
```

The problem is the date it would be formated in UTC

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the graph doesn't display when I paste your code into my Codepen :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of oddities. Your `xAxis` is set to datetime which is good. With a point interval of one day - also good. But, if you look at your `series.data` you are sending in data formatted like:

```
{
    name: "Gold",
    x: "1233.6",
    y: 1233.6
}
```

You are setting the `y` here:

```
var date = String(items[1]);
```

You should be using `items[0]`. Now, you also have to parse this string into javascript time. Something like this can work:

```
var arr = String(items[0]).split("-");
var date = Date.UTC(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

However, now your chart throws error that date is not sorted. See updated pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZgmKY).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also here, when I apply your code I don't get the graph to work anymore..

Comment: The reason is because your data in that file you are parsing is not sorted. if you run my code and then look at the navigator series you can see that there are cases where the line backtracks on itself. If you make your lines segment just the first 20 entries you can see this reflected in the main chart plot area. There are various ways to fix this sorting.